# Invalid top-level property "network_mode" from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use network_mode: "host" on docker-compose but it was rejected.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:
  hello:
    image: hello-world:latest
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_hello_1 ... done
Attaching to tmp_hello_1
hello_1  |
hello_1  | Hello from Docker!
hello_1  | This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
:
tmp_hello_1 exited with code 0
```

OK. Let me use network_mode: "host"

```
$ nano docker-compose.yml
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
network_mode: "host"
services:
  hello:
    image: hello-world:latest
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "network_mode". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, secrets, configs, and extensions starting with "x-".
```

WHY!? this is official isn't it?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

```
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfca03
$  cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.04 (Disco Dingo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.04"
VERSION_ID="19.04"
```

Answer (score 1):

network_mode is not top level property. Write it under service.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  hello:
    network_mode: "host"
    image: hello-world:latest
```